# autoclick with delay between each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, shiny

I have learnt to autoplay an animating slinder input using the following code. It autoplay with a given delay. But what I want to do is introduce a delay between every clicks. Not just after page loading also between every click I want a delay. This is becasue plot takes time to draw and display.

Any help please? The below is the code I used:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
        sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                    min = 10, max = 500, value = 100,
                    animate=T),
        tags$script("$(document).ready(function(){
                        setTimeout(function() {$('.slider-animate-button').click()},10);
                    });")
                )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare a `handler()` method for your click event and then specify the delay function inside it.

*For example:*

```
function clickHandler() {
  setTimeout(function(){
     //do something
   }, 10);
}
$('.slider-animate-button').onClick(clickHandler);
```